# Parsing nested JSON data with angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ngfor

I'm using Angular5 and I'm receiving some JSON data from an API that looks something like this

```
{
  Cars: {

      BMW: {
        M3: {
          description: 'BMW M3 car description'
          features: [
            {
              name: 'feature name',
              description: 'feature description'
            }
          ]
        },
        M4: {
          description: 'BMW M4 car description'
          features: [
            {
              name: 'feature name',
              description: 'feature description'
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      Audi: {
        features: [
          {
            name: 'extra feature 1',
            description: 'extra feature 1 description'
          }
        ],
        R8: {
          description: 'Audi R8 car description'
          features: [
            {
              name: 'feature name',
              description: 'feature description'
            }
          ]
        },
        R6: {
          description: 'Audi R6 car description'
          features: [...]
        }
      }
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, I need to render this in the template in a structure like this for example:

```
M3
  features...
M4
  features...
R8
  features...
R6
  features...
```

but the problem is that these car model objects (M3, M4, R8...) are provided as objects inside objects (instead of an array of objects that I can loop through easily with a simple ngFor).

Also, in the 'Audi' Object, you will notice that there is an extra "features" object at the same level as 'R8' and 'R6',

this needs to be added for both 'R8' and 'R6' objects with the key "extra-features"

(so if there's a 'features' object at the same level as the cars models, it should be moved inside the cars models objects with the key "extra-features")

so the Audi Object should eventually look like this:

```
Audi: {

  R8: {
    description: 'Audi R8 car description'
    features: [
      {
        name: 'feature name',
        description: 'feature description'
      }
    ],
    extra-features: [
      {
        name: 'extra feature 1',
        description: 'extra feature 1 description'
      }
    ]
  },
  R6: {
    description: 'Audi R6 car description'
    features: [...],
    extra-features: [
      {
        name: 'extra feature 1',
        description: 'extra feature 1 description'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the final result to be rendered in the template is like this:

```
M3
  features...
M4
  features...
R8
  features...
  extra-features...
R6
  features...
  extra-features...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
const cars;

myCars = YourJsonData;
myCars.forEach((car, index, self) => {
  cars.push(index);
  car.forEach((model, indexM, self) {
     cars[index].push(indexM);
     model.forEach((feat, indexF, self) {
       cars[index][indexM].push([indexF => indexF.value]);
     });
  });
});
```

Could be optimized, not very good with JS.

And in template something like:

```
*ngFor="let car in cars"
*ngIf="car.features"
*ngIf="car.extra-features"
```